# How to fix this error message? syntax error, unexpected tIVAR

Tags: ruby, sockets, syntax-error, iostream

I'm trying to run some tests on my code, but I'm running into a problem.  For a very simple line of code, I get a weird error message.  This test is to make sure my server can receive info from one of my clients.

The tests and file run fine without this line:

```
client_1.@socket.puts("This gives an error.")
```

Including that bit of code gives this error:

```
macowner:WAR3 macowner$ ruby ServerTests1.rb
ServerTests1.rb:160: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting '('
        client_1.@socket.puts("Output for Server to receive.")  #Error
                        ^
```

Help is greatly appreciated.  I get this error fairly frequently, but I have no idea what it means (even with searching for it).

```
enter code here
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'socket'
require_relative 'WarGame_Class.rb'
require_relative 'ModifiedPlayer_Class.rb'
require_relative 'DeckClass.rb'

class WarServer

    def initialize(host, port)  
        @socket_server = TCPServer.new(host, port)
        @players = [Player.new, Player.new]
        @deck = CardDeck.new
        @deck.deal_cards(@players[0].cards, @players[1].cards)
        game = WarGame.new
        @clients = {} # keys are sockets, values are players

    end

    def client_keys(key)
      @clients.keys[key] # this should work
    end

    def input   #input reader function
        @input
    end


    def close
        @socket_server.close
    end


    def capture_input   ##input client to get what they wrote
        @input = @clients.keys[0].read_nonblock(1000) # arbitrary max number of bytes

    end

    def accept_client
        #Hash here to link client to player? (or game?)
        client = @socket_server.accept
        @clients[client] = @players[@clients.size]
    #   puts "clients key 0: #{@clients.keys[0]}"
        puts
    #   puts "clients values: #{@clients.values}"
        if @clients.size == 2
            start_game#####################!!!! Starts game if two clients  can put client messages in start game
        end
    end


    def start_game  ##############!!!
        @clients.keys[0].puts  "Welcome to War.  Please press enter to play your card"
        @clients.keys[1].puts  "Welcome to War.  Please press enter to play your card"

    end

end

class MockWarClient
    def initialize
        @socket = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 2012)
    end

    def output
        @output
    end

    def input
        @input
    end

    def capture_output  #need to add (socket)?  How else read from specific socket?
        @output = @socket.read_nonblock(1000) # arbitrary max number of bytes
    rescue
        @output = "capture_output error."
    end

    def write_input
        @input = @war_server.client_keys.write_nonblock(1000)
    end
end

class WarServerTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase


    def setup   #This would be like our INITIALIZE Function
        #anything is available through out all tests (i.e., instance vars)
        @war_server = WarServer.new('localhost', 2012)
    end


    def teardown
        @war_server.close
    end

def test_server_capture_output_from_client

        client_1 = MockWarClient.new
        @war_server.accept_client

        client_2 = MockWarClient.new
        @war_server.accept_client

        client_1.@socket.puts("Output for Server to receive.")  #Line I need to fix

        #SOCKETforSERVER
        #clien_n.SOCKETforSERVER.puts''
        #Replace puts with write_nonblock, perhaps  
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to access the `@socket` instance variable then you just need another accessor method in `MockWarClient`:

```
def socket
  @socket
end
```

and the say `client_1.socket.puts(...)` to use it. You could also use [`attr_reader`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) to simplify things:

```
class MockWarClient
  attr_reader :socket, :input, :output

  def initialize
    @socket = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 2012)
  end

  def capture_output  #need to add (socket)?  How else read from specific socket?
    @output = @socket.read_nonblock(1000) # arbitrary max number of bytes
  rescue
    @output = "capture_output error."
  end

  def write_input
    @input = @war_server.client_keys.write_nonblock(1000)
  end
end
```

That will create the three accessor methods for you.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot call a method named `@socket` in a usual way as you are trying in `client_1.@socket`. That method name is very unusual because it is confusing with an instance variable, and it is doubtful that you actually have such method, but if you do, then the way to call such method is:

```
client_1.send(:@socket)
```

Comment: I don't think they're trying to call a method named `@socket`, they're obviously trying to access the instance variable.

Comment: It must be a method, because you never send a message using a dot with a variable of any kind.  To the parser, it has to be a method.

Comment: @mu is too short
I'm a pretty amateur programmer...aaaand I think I'm trying to call the variable there (because I am trying to pass information through the socket...)

Comment: @vgoff: Assuming of course that the person knows Ruby but if they were good at Ruby they would be trying to access an instance variable in another object that way...

Comment: It was a good-natured poke at your comment, @muistooshort.  And a chance for the OP to hopefully read it and gather a little bit of information from it as well, maybe.  Yes, I believe Yallo was probably wanting to pass a variable as well.

Comment: @vgoff: Fair enough, maybe I'm just a bit cranky this evening.